# Apache htaccess: Unable to use RewriteCond HTTPS and HTTP_USER_AGENT together

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, user-agent

I'm trying to rewrite a URL to a specific domain based on the user agent. But if i change the domain to **https** i get a 500 Internal Server Error.

This htaccess rewrite rule is working as expected:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Facebot)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

This example throws a 500 Internal Server Error:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Facebot)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

I tried the following but the user agent condition will not work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Facebot)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

What am i doing wrong? How can i solve my issue?

Comment: And if you visit `https://example.com/?url=%{REQUEST_URI}` directly, with an expected user agent, what do you get?

Comment: Accessing the url directly works as expected. Tested it using Facebook Debugger.

Comment: When you get 500 error in browser check your Apache log to see what is exact cause of 500 error.

Comment: You probably need `SSLProxyEngine On`, and you should really be configuring a proxy properly in your`<VirtualHost>` before rewriting to it.

Comment: @anubhava i don't find anything in the logs. I'm using a shared hosting with cPanel.

Comment: @Walf unfortunately i don't have access to httpd because i'm using a shared hosting service.

Comment: Do you need to proxy the request and return the result *exactly* as that endpoint returns it? Can you just ping it from a script instead? You trying to put it over https suggests it could be on a public network; of so, why proxy it?

Comment: @Walf This is to prerender a SPA, so i need to show the end result. I just want to hide the prerender domain. For example, if someone access http://example.com i don't want the prerender.example.com domain to be shown.

Comment: What matters here is that if you cannot proxy over https with `.htaccess`, you need to find another way to do it.

Comment: @Walf as a temporary solution, i won't use https on the domain.

Comment: If it's going over the public 'Net to another server, I wouldn't do that. You're better off rewriting to a tiny script that will perform the request securely and return the response (+ any important headers).

Comment: @Walf can you provide my an example of such a script?

Comment: It could be as simple as a `file_get_contents($url, stream_context_create(['http' => ['user_agent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'ignore_errors' => true]]))` then passing on relevant headers from `$http_response_header`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Walf! I'll give it a try :)